# What replaces FindControl for WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am converting my app from WebForm to WinForm and I am trying to determine what checkboxes the user selected. In WebForm `FindControl()` allowed me to find the checkboxes. In WinForms it's not the same or at least it won't allow me to do so. What can I use to find if a checkbox is selected in a gridview and/or how can I change this to allow `FindControl()` to work?

Here is where I find the controls

```
var rows = dropdeadGridView.Rows;
bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)rows[j].FindControl("SelectCheckBox")).Checked;//problem
if (isChecked)
{
    values += rows[j].Cells[2] + ",";
    CurrentOrders = values;
}
```

My problem lies above because then below I put it into an array and separate them to pass to my query.

```
string[] o = CurrentOrders.ToString().Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < o.Length; i++)
{
    SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();
    try
    {
        using (dbConn)
        {
            SqlCommand addJob = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE ODetail SET L_NUMBER = @L_NUMBER WHERE S_O_NUMBER = @SONumber", dbConn);
            addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONumber", o[i]);
            addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_NUMBER", lNumber.Text);
            dbConn.Open();
            addJob.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw ex;
     }
```

Error Code

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: forget winforms. It is a really old (legacy) technology that's not recommended for any new projects. Only to maintain legacy applications. The XAML + DataBinding paradigm is really much closer to the Web paradigm than winforms. All current UI technologies in the .Net World are XAML-based. By learning XAML you're opening yourself a path into modern technologies and code reuse. Whereas all the (horrible) code you throw into winforms will be stuck into winforms forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `FindControl` in WinForm. You can simply do:

```
bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
```

*Assuming you are comparing first row and your check box is in 3rd column*

You can also iterate each row to get the checkbox selected value like:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    bool checkBoxValue = Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells[2].Value); 
}
```

Comment: So since mine is the last row it would be Rows[5].Cells[2].Value since it the last column.

Comment: Which is more beneficial in this case?

Comment: @user3727649, sure try it, or you can have a selected row and get its values.

Comment: @user3727649, more beneficial ?? in what sense, that is purely depends on the requirement, I just showed you how to get the value of Selected checkbox from a `DataGridView`

Comment: I wasn't sure if for some reason one was easier to work with or more manipulitable.